# Frequency distinct values grouped by date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distinct, frequency

I am trying to get the frequency of unique ID values for each month of the last year. However, I don't get the outcome.. including the error message "SELECT list expression references column user_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated".

How can I get the count of unique IDs in each month and them group them by month?

What I tried:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE
  date >= '2020-09-01'
GROUP BY
  month
```

I want something like this:

| month | count of unique user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 200 |
| ... | ... |
| 12 | 250 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM TABLE
WHERE date >= '2020-09-01'
GROUP BY 1;
```

I would advise you to include the year in the query.  In BigQuery, this is simplest using `DATE_TRUNC()`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) as month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM TABLE
WHERE date >= '2020-09-01'
GROUP BY 1;
```